# Windows 10 stuck on loading screen - white circle of death?

Tags: windows-10

After a buggy install of Eset endpoint antivirus this machine crashed, rebooted, and has been stuck in a ['white circle of death'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esA61.jpg) ever since.

Any clues - I don't seem to be able to get it into safe mode thanks to the Win10 changes.

Comment: Is the antivirus compatible with Windows 10? Did you check that? Is the antivirus just holding the Windows 10 from doing its job?

Comment: @Prasanna yes, it is a Win10 version of the software.

Comment: Try to see if you can get email support from the antivirus vendor in the first place stating this issue. You can boot ur system using a Live CD/DVD and be able to make changes (delete) to certain folders - if the antivirus vendor advises to do so. May be you will see through this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by McAfee crapware.

The machine booted after being left alone for 2 hours and we were eventually, albeit slowly able to uninstall the McAfee crap.